# Why is `goog.base(this)` necessary in addition to `goog.inherits()`?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, google-closure-library

In this snippet of Google Closure javascript code involving a constructor, why is `goog.base(this);` necessary? Doesn't `Foo` already inherit from Disposable with `goog.inherits(foo, goog.Disposable);`?

```javascript
goog.provide('Foo');

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.Disposable}
 */
Foo = function() {
  goog.base(this);
}     
goog.inherits(foo, goog.Disposable);

foo.prototype.doSomething = function(){
  ...
}

foo.prototype.disposeInternal = function(){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [goog.inherits(childConstructor, parentConstructor)](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js#L2181)

`goog.inherits()` establishes the *prototype chain* from the child constructor
to the parent constructor.

```javascript
/**
 * Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another.
 * @param {Function} childCtor Child class.
 * @param {Function} parentCtor Parent class.
 */
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /** @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  /** @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

In addition to prototype properties, constructors may have "own" properties
(i.e. instance-specific properties added to `this`). Since `goog.inherits()`
does not call the parent constructor, own properties are not copied to the
child constructor and any initialization code in the parent does not get
executed. For these reasons, the standard pattern is to [chain constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object) as in the following example.

```
/**
 * @param {string} name The parent's name.
 * @constructor
 */
var Parent = function(name) {
  /**
   * @type {string}
   * @private
   */
  this.name_ = name;
}

/**
 * @param {string} name The child's name.
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Parent}
 */
var Child = function(name) {
  Parent.call(this, name);
}
goog.inherits(Child, Parent);
```

### [goog.base(self, opt_methodName, var_args)](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js#L2239)

`goog.base()` is a helper function for calling parent methods so that you do
not need to explicitly use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply).

> If [goog.base()] is called from a constructor, then this calls the
>   superclass contructor with arguments 1-N.
>
> If this is called from a prototype method, then you must pass the name of
>   the method as the second argument to this function. If you do not,
>   you will get a runtime error. This calls the superclass' method with
>   arguments 2-N.
>
> This function only works if you use `goog.inherits` to express inheritance
>   relationships between your classes.

In Closure code it is common to chain constructors with `goog.base()` rather
than calling the parent constructor explicitly.

```
/**
 * @param {string} name The child's name.
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Parent}
 */
var Child = function(name) {
  goog.base(this, name);
}
goog.inherits(Child, Parent);
```

## Further Reading

- [*Inheritance Patterns in JavaScript* by Michael Bolin](http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php)
- [*An Examination of goog.base()* by Michael Bolin](http://bolinfest.com/essays/googbase.html)
- [*Closure: The Definitive Guide* by Michael Bolin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871)
- [*JavaScript Patterns* by Stoyan Stefanov](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) (see Chapter 6: "Code Reuse Patterns" for a detailed analysis of the pattern used to implement `goog.inherits()` - *Classical Pattern #5--A Temporary Constructor*)

Comment: As somebody who is coming over from the `Java` world, would it make sense to say that `base` is to `inherits` as `super()` is to `extends`?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by how the function is *called*, not where it's defined (as it is in Java, C#, and C++). So to make `this` *within* the call to `goog.Disposable` be the `this` of where you're calling it, you have to use `.call` or `.apply`. Otherwise, if you just called `goog.Disposable()`, within the call `this` would be `goog`.

Basically, there are two ways to set `this` for the function you're calling:

1. Use `obj.func()` or `obj["func"]()` notation — e.g., make the call as part of the same overall expression where you're retrieving a property from the object. This tells the engine that within the call, you want `this` to refer to `obj`.
2. Use `call` or `apply` to be more explicit about it by supplying the object to use as `this` as the first argument. The only difference between `call` and `apply` is how you supply other arguments: With `call`, you supply them as discrete args, e.g. `foo.call(obj, 1, 2, 3)` calls `foo` with `this` set to `obj` and the arguments `1`, `2`, and `3`. With `apply`, you supply the arguments as an array-like second argument: `foo.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]);` (note the `[` and `]`; e.g. `var a = [1, 2, 3]; foo.call(obj, a);`

More to explore:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Can you make a canonical answer of this so we can use it as duplicate, I see you make this answer 100 times a day :D

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, it's *amazing* how many different contexts this comes up in. :-) Sometimes it's an outright duplicate, other times (like this one) it's *effectively* a duplicate but you can see why someone wouldn't have found an earlier answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can see

```
Foo = function() {
  goog.base(this); //call parent constructor
}     
goog.inherits(foo, goog.Disposable);
```

As:

```
public class Foo extends Disposable(){
  public Foo(){
    super(); // call parent constructor
  }
}
```