# Inheritance using Google Closure

Tags: javascript, inheritance, google-closure

I have a base class named 'baseScreen' as follows:

```
digient.casino.ui.baseScreen = function() {
    goog.debug.Logger.getLogger('demo').info('baseScreen');
    this.background                             =   goog.dom.createDom('div', {'class': 'backgroundHolder'}, '');
    console.log(this);
}

digient.casino.ui.baseScreen.background         =   null;

digient.casino.ui.baseScreen.prototype.load     =   function() {
    var self                                    =   this;
    goog.debug.Logger.getLogger('demo').info('baseScreen : load');
    goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, this.background);
    <!-- screen setup code goes here -->
};

digient.casino.ui.baseScreen.prototype.resize  =   function(newSize) {
    goog.debug.Logger.getLogger('demo').info('baseScreen : resize');
};
```

in `onLoad`, if I load baseScreen as

```
var sc = new digient.casino.ui.baseScreen();
sc.load();
```

its working fine.

Then I derive a screen named `registerScreen` as follows:

```
digient.casino.ui.registerScreen = function() {                                                     
    goog.debug.Logger.getLogger('demo').info('registerScreen');                                     
    digient.casino.ui.baseScreen.call();
};                                                                                                  
goog.inherits(digient.casino.ui.registerScreen, digient.casino.ui.baseScreen);
```

When I try to load object of `registerScreen`, its throwing an error on the line where I try to append `this.background` to `document.body` and weirdly `console.log(this)` in line 4 prints `window` object instead of `baseScreen` or `registerScreen` object.

Whats wrong with my code? Do I need to override load, resize in my derived class? (tried this, but failure) or any other problem?

Comment: See: [Why is `goog.base(this)` necessary in addition to `goog.inherits()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122608/why-is-goog-basethis-necessary-in-addition-to-goog-inherits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `baseScreen` will the current `registerScreen` instance:

```
digient.casino.ui.baseScreen.call(this);
```

Otherwise, your function call is equivalent to `digient.casino.ui.baseScreen()`, hence `this` refers to the global object `window`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could also replace the call mentioned by @felix-kling with:

```
goog.base(this);
```

which does the exact same thing.

One note about goog.base, from the docs:

> If this is called from a constructor, then this calls the superclass constructor with arguments 1-N. If this is called from a prototype method, then you must pass the name of the method as the second argument to this function. If you do not, you will get a runtime error.

**see also:**

- http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html
- http://bolinfest.com/essays/googbase.html)